# StackExchange's OAuth login broken - identifying an HTTPS request as non-HTTPS

Tags: bug, status-completed, ssl, oauth

Recently (as in, the last few hours - however, it may have been broken for a few days), I've been unable to login via Stack Exchange for a third party application with Stack Exchange's [OAuth support](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/authentication). When attempting to login, I'm presented with the following error screen:

[image]

Transcription of the error page:

> ### Application Login Failure
>
> An error occurred while login into an application.
>
> #### Error Details
>
> **error**: invalid_request
> **error description**: OAuth request must be over HTTPS

Note that the URL *is* HTTPS, and so is the `redirect_uri`.

I've reproduced this on two independently developed applications and on two distinct networks (my work machine, and mobile).

Comment: Happens on MetaSmoke ([Charcoal Teams report](https://stackoverflow.com/c/charcoal/q/579/98)).

Comment: Does this happen on https://stackoverflow.com/oauth ? Note: the docs do not use stackexchange.com :)

Comment: A tweak for this route is going out now which should resolve your issue (please report back! - I don't want to mark this status-completed until we confirm you're good). Overall, migrating to stackoverflow.com/oauth will be the supported way - we'll be removing the old stackexchange.com path eventually as part of overall infrastructure cleanup (leaving only redirects).

Comment: @Nick it’s fixed!! Thanks!

Comment: @NickCraver Oh, I hadn't noticed the documentation had changed, I'd just re-used code from a few years ago. I'll make sure to get the endpoint updated, thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This was a bug that crept in as part of the .NET Core migration (the only one I’m aware of, so close!). Sorry about that, a fix has been deployed now. Note that we’ll redirect these URLs but the preferred method in the docs is using stackoverflow.com instead as your endpoint (its a different app on our backend).

Thanks for the quick report, it’s much appreciated!